# sqlite database didn't update table in my flask webhook python code

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I try to update my sqlite database using flask webhook.

It seems commands line work fine if I type manually in the python console but my flask webhook didn't update my SQLite database. It seems the apps fail at the "cursor.execute()" line.

here is my webhook code:

```
@app.route('/trendanalyser', methods=['POST'])
def trendanalyser():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    if data['passphrase'] == config.WEBHOOK_PASSPHRASE:
#Init update variables
        tastate = data['TrendAnalyser']
        date_format = datetime.today()
        date_update = date_format.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        update_data = ((tastate), (date_update))
#Database connection
        connection = sqlite3.connect('TAState15min.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
#Database Update
        update_query = """Update TrendAnalyser set state = ?, date = ? where id = 1"""
        cursor.execute(update_query, update_data)
        connection.commit()
        return("Record Updated successfully")
        cursor.close()
    else:
        return {"invalide passphrase"}
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong with my code ?

if it's can help, here is my database structure (my db creation):

```
#Database connection
conn = sqlite3.connect("TAState15min.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
#Create table
sql_query = """ CREATE TABLE TrendAnalyser (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    state text,
    date text
)"""
cursor.execute(sql_query)
#Create empty row with ID at 1
insert_query = """INSERT INTO TrendAnalyser
                          (id, state, date)
                          VALUES (1, 'Null', 'Null');"""
cursor.execute(insert_query)
conn.commit()
#Close database connexion
cursor.close()
```

**I finally found the issue, webhooks need the full path to the SQLite database to work fine. I just start to code in python, it was a noob issue... **

Comment: I assume the error is at this line by testing with return commands. all return before this line pass but not after. the error returnet by the webhook sended is:  "500 Internal server error"

Comment: Don't add a solution in a question. Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: Thanks. I'm new on the forum, was looking for that but didn't found at the first look. I close my question now by the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue, webhooks need the full path to the SQLite database to work fine. I just start to code in python, it was a noob issue...

Comment: to help others with a similar problem, maybe post the changed coded that resolved the issue for you.